# Send emails with flask and outside context / cronjobs

Tags: python, flask

I have a project which is structured similar to the [overholt](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone) and [fbone](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone) example. I can send emails from all my blueprints fine, but struggle to send outside. E.g. from within a cron script or celery task.
I keep getting the error `working outside of application context`

app/factory.py

```
from flask import Flask
from .extensions import mail

def create_app(package_name, package_path, settings_override=None,
           register_security_blueprint=True):

    app = Flask(package_name, instance_relative_config=True)

    mail.init_app(app)
    register_blueprints(app, package_name, package_path)
    app.wsgi_app = HTTPMethodOverrideMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)

    return app
```

app/extensions.py

```
from flask_mail import Mail
mail = Mail()
```

app/frontend/admin.py

```
bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__, url_prefix='/admin', static_folder='static')

@bp.route('/')
def admin():
    msg = Message(......)
    mail.send(msg)
```

Everything up until here works fine. Now I have a separate module in app which has some cron scripts which now fail.

app/cron/alerts.py

```
from ..extensions import mail
from flask.ext.mail import Message

def alert():
    msg = Message('asdfasdf', sender='hello@example.com', recipients=['hello@example.com'])
    msg.body = 'hello'
    mail.send(msg)
```

Which produces the error. How can I get around this?

```
raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

Comment: @MarcK I did see that one but i'm not sure where i get `app` from?

Comment: @lennard Where do you get the `app` in `app/factory.py` in your example?

Comment: @lord63.j I've updated the code with where i get app from in factory.py

Comment: @MarcK How can I accept the duplicate link?

Comment: @lennard I don't think you actually accept it. The community comes through and marks it as one. Glad you got your code working.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You need use [Flask-Mail](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/):

```
from flask_mail import Mail
mail = Mail(app)
```

Comment: @lennard, check documentation. it's not big.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend going with celery. For the context problem I have found my solution in the following.

Have a look at this:

[Miguel Grinberg's Blogpost on celery](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)

Or if you are using the factory pattern in your application:

[Celery with Factory Pattern](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern)

The second one is some kind of further/extended reading.
Both of them helped me a lot. (The second one also solved a context issue for me)